# Grouping of actvie events given Start and End date (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the challenge that I have a table with start and end date of an event:

```
Event Start       End
A     01Jan2018   01Mar2018
B     01Feb2018   01Apr2018
```

I would like to have a table as output with a group by of active events in a month:

```
Year Month count_active_events
2018 1     1
2018 2     2
2018 3     2
2018 4     1
```

Can anyone think of a SQL statement that makes this request feasible?

THX
Lazloo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table([Event] char(1), [Start] date  ,    [End] date);
insert into @tbl Values
('A'  ,   '01Jan2018',   '01Mar2018'),
('B'  ,   '01Feb2018',   '01Apr2018');
declare @start date,
        @end date;
select @start = min([Start]), @end = max([End]) from @tbl;

with cte as(
    select @start dt from @tbl
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt) from cte
    where  dateadd(month, 1, dt) <= @end
)

select datepart(month, c.dt), datepart(year, c.dt), count(distinct [Event]) from cte c
left join @tbl t on c.dt between t.Start and t.[End]
group by datepart(month, c.dt), datepart(year, c.dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method generates the dates and then does the calculation using a correlated subquery or `apply`:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2018-01-01' as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2018-04-01'
     )
select d.dte,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.start <= d.dte and t.end >= d.dte
       ) as num_active
from dates d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `apply` with recursive `cte` to generate start event dates   :

```
with tt1 as (
     select event, cast(start as date) start, cast([end] as date) [end]
     from table
     union all
     select event, dateadd(month, 1, start), [end]
     from tt1
     where start < [end]
)

select year(tt.dt), month(tt.dt), tt1.cnt
from table t cross apply
     ( values (start), ([end]) 
     ) tt (dt) outer apply
     ( select count(*) cnt
       from tt1
       where year(tt1.start) = year(tt.dt) and
             month(tt1.start) = month(tt.dt)
     ) tt1;
```